# how to handle parameters in a raw submit form in rails 3.2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I handle a parameter passed in from a raw HTML form?

in /views/feeders/index.html.erb:

```
<form action="/feeders/extract/" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <input type="text" name="url" value="" id="url">    
    <p><input type="submit" value="submit"></p>
</form>
```

in /controllers/feeders_controller.rb

```
class FeedersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @url=params[:url]
  end

  def show

  end

  def extract
    @url=params[:url]
    redirect_to :controller => 'feeders', :action => 'show'
  end
end
```

in routes.rb:

```
 root :to => 'feeders#index'
  match '/feeders/extract/:url' => 'feeders#extract', :via => :post
  match '/feeders/show/' => 'feeders#show'
```

I keep getting

```
Routing Error

No route matches [POST] "/feeders/extract"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

point #1

make your route as

```
post "feeders/extract" => "feeders#extract"
```

your route 
    match '/feeders/extract/:url' => 'feeders#extract', :via => :post

will allow urls like

```
POST /feeders/extract/somevalue => params[:url] => 'somevalue'
POST /feeders/extract/123       => params[:url] => '123'
```

Try "rake routes" to know more

point #2: after you have followed #1 above

As I am trying to understand your needs from your comments, what you need is as below

in your routes.rb

```
post "feeders/extract" => "feeders#show"
match '/feeders/show/' => 'feeders#show'
```

and then perhaps you wont need extract action in your FeedersController.rb, show action would get called for extract call with params[:url]

point #3(alternative to #2): after you have followed #1 above

simply edit your controller as

```
render :show # redirect_to :controller => 'feeders', :action => 'show'
```

instead of redirect there

Hence you can go with either #1,#2 or #1,#3 as per your needs.

You should go with #1,#2 if "extract" action/process has more meaning there, I mean to end user.

Hope I understood your scenario :)

Answer (score 0):

The post request is trying to hit `/feeders/extract/`, but you don't have any routes that match that (the closest I see is `/feeder/extract/:url`).

Changing your route to `match '/feeders/extract/' => 'feeders#extract', :via => :post` should do the trick.

Once the request is routed correctly to the extract action, you will still have to `params[:url]`.

Comment: But I want to pass in :url as the parameter (and render it in feeders#show). How can I do that?

Comment: Right in your code example, you are not doing anything with `@url`.  If you want the value of `@url` in your show action, you should save in your model and retrieve it again in your show action.  In an MVC architecture, your model is be responsible for knowing how to get the data.